# Python script unable to validate App Keys with Fuel SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication, fuel-sdk, python

I am trying to run a basic Python script to search for a subscriber but it is failing to authenticate.

I've set up Python (successfully ran a Hello World script), installed FuelSDK, created a server-to-server app at SFMC App Center to retrieve my ClientID and ClientSecret. I've modified config.python to hold my ClientID and ClientSecret and changed file location of `wsdl_file_local_loc` to  `ExactTargetWSDL.xml`.

I get the following error when I try to run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search_subscriber.py", line 3, in <module>
    myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\FuelSDK\client.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.refresh_token()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\FuelSDK\client.py", line 192, in refresh_token
    raise Exception('Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: ' + repr(r.json()))
Exception: Unable to validate App Keys(ClientID/ClientSecret) provided: {u'errorcode': 10005, u'message': u'clientId is required', u'documentation': u''}`
```

I'm not a programmer and I tried reading other answers with similar questions but I don't really know if they are applicable solutions to my problem. As far as I can tell, I copied and pasted the ID and Secret and there appears to be no typos.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v0.9.4, lines 22 and 23:

`client_id = None
client_secret = None`

Putting my credentials in there is the only change I made and it works just fine for me. You're entering them "as_strings", yeah?

Did you install through pip? There's a few dependencies it'd install for you like suds and requests if you're new to Python and didn't have them already - feels like you have some already if you're getting responses but just want to be sure.

Comment: modifying `config.python` did not work but modifying `client.py` as you suggested works. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this been struggling with this for a minutes. I have added my credenttials here and it still isnt working.

Comment: IT workeD!!! I had already liked this ages ago but not tried it. All I had to do was refresh Jupyter